# how to have one mailbox with two users of different domain(in a forest)?

Tags: exchange, email-server, microsoft

i'm setting new domain and exchange server, lets call it "test.com" and also i have and old domain "test.org". I want my clients login to new domain with the old account, and have mailbox. also i want if users login with new account, have access to the same mailbox. i tried linked mailbox but its not working with the account of new domain. maybe its better to explain in this way:

I want to have 1 mailbox for two users "user@test.org and user@test.com", and can open the mail when i login with each user.

so how may I do this?

Comment: You can try to add the second email address in the user mailbox so that the messages sent to that mailbox can be received by the user.

Comment: hi , thanks for the responsible, but that would not help, because in the case you said, the clients can cant have the same mail box when they login with their two accounts,